# How i can create a new user group in PrestaShop with all enable modules by functions?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

How i can create a new user group in PrestaShop 1.6 with all enable modules by functions?
i`ll try like this example:

`$res = Db::getInstance()->execute('INSERT INTO ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'group        (id_group, date_add, date_upd) VALUES (NULL, NOW(), NOW())');
 $last_id = Db::getInstance()->Insert_ID();
 $res &= Db::getInstance()->execute('INSERT INTO ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'group_lang (id_group, id_lang, name) VALUES ' . $sql);`

but a new group created with all disable modules.
How i can enable all modules in Presta code?
hlp pls!

Comment: with sql i doing that like that:             `$controllers = Module::getModulesInstalled();
            $id_modules = array();
            foreach($controllers as $key=>$id_module){
                $id_modules[$key] = $id_module['id_module'];
            }
            $shops = Shop::getShops(true, null, true);
            $ress = Group::addModulesRestrictions($last_id, $id_modules, $shops);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert the Group Id and Shop Id in **ps_module_group** table along with the Module Id.

Example:

```
$res = Db::getInstance()->execute('INSERT INTO ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'module_group (id_module, id_shop, id_group) VALUES ($module_id, 1, $group_id)');
```